# How can I visit to a virtual machine localhost from the main os browser?

Tags: localhost, emulation

I'm emulating Ubuntu on my mac and I want to use it as local server to test websites.

I'm using wmware tools for emulation.

How can I visit to the localhost in the emulated Ubuntu from the browser in osx ? I've installed Apache on the virtual machine but I would like to access to the websites even from osx

thanks

Comment: Your virtual machine has an IP address - assuming that you have set up networking. Just enter that IP address in your OS X browser. That's how such things worked out for me, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://localhost in a browser is the same as http://127.0.0.1. 127.0.0.1 is the IP address of what is called the loopback device. To access the web page from another computer that is on the same network:

example: http://192.168.0.10

replace 192.168.0.10 with whatever the IP address is of your virtual ubuntu machine.

Also, you may be able to call up the web page on the ubuntu vm by using the name of the ubuntu machine.

example: http://ubuntu-pc

Comment: Ok thanks, the virtual machine ip works, but how can I assign a name to the virtual machine or how can I know the correct one ? THe one I can read in vm library (Ubuntu) doesn't work

Comment: I guess the name is ubuntu since I can read this in the terminal : patrick@ubuntu:~$

Comment: Yep that's right, ubuntu would be the machine name. If http://ubuntu does not work, then I would take a look at how your networking is set up. Bridged/NAT... but not a big deal as you can use the IP address. This will only work on your internal network of course. If you wanted to access the site from the public internet, then you would need to do some port forwarding on your firewall/router.